# Visual Studio gets stuck on opening a sql project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

We are trying to setup a sql project, in a new machine with Windows 7, VS 2010 with SP1 & SSDT 2010 (installed SSDT 2010 from iso image). But getting the below message when I open the sqlproj.

**'Verifying your model is synchronized with your source files. Your database will be ready in 12734 operations are completed.'
And the number keeps on increasing**. And it keeps on running in the background.

Tried re-installing SSDT, VS 2010 but no help.

Created a new database project for Northwind db, and had the same issue. Ran  procmon and saw it's just going over and over the same files.

It works fine in another system with similar configuration.

**EDIT**

The issue seems to be related to TFS, if we unbind from TFS it works fine. But not sure about the exact cause.

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My suggestion is if you are using source control such as Git and you have just switched branches and you are hitting this issue is to use `git clean` which will remove untracked files (which VS and SSDT are choking up on)

```
git clean -fdx
```

Not sure what to use if you are on TFS or SVN or HG.. but same idea applies

Comment: This seemed to work for me, especially as sometimes there a lot of untracked files created by SSDT

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this several more times! Really pleased to have got VS 2015 finally working. Many thanks.

Comment: This is a fix in sorts but...I just wondered if anyone knew which file in particular is causing the system to lock.

Comment: Don't forget to commit any uncommitted work before doing this (like I just did) :(

Answer (score 6):

I deleted the .suo file in the .vs folder in the root of solution directory.  This fixed it for me.  I think this is the best and least damaging answer as it preserves your modified files and some of your other settings (of course some settings such as your start up project will be lost)

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2015. It was a project that was converted from 2013.

Answer (score 2):

MCafee antivirus was causing the issue. The issue got resolved after disabling the antivirus.

Comment: Its _an_ answer, and a worthy one. Virus scanners often detect programming tools as being a problem or the realtime scan engines insist on scanning each and every file, causing this kind of slowdown.